# Free paper trading with api

Tags: programming, trading, broker

Im currently using Alpaca but I want to switch the service since it had some major outages. Does anyone know a good reliable *free* broker with paper trading and api so I can test my trading bot.
Thanks

Comment: I believe that [Interactive brokers](https://www.interactivebrokers.com/en/home.php) gives you the ability to open a paper-trading account with (limited) access to their API. They also have commission-free trading on US stocks and ETFs. Does this help? :-)

Comment: Yes it dies help thank you very much :)